# Overflow hidden changes the content location

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have div with 300px as width, inside the div I have placed 5 labels. The Labels width is greater than the div width, so I have set the "overflow" of the div to "hidden", which hides the labels that exceeds the div width.

[image: div overflow with hidden]
Using a dropdown, I have changed the "overflow" to "auto" which allow me to scroll and view the remaining labels. 
[image: div overflow with auto]

After I scrolled to the end for viewing the remaining labels, I have changed the overflow of div to "hidden". Now the last labels are showing and the labels from the first are hidden.
[image]

I want to show the labels series0 and series1 as before after I changed the overflow from "auto" to "hidden". Is it possible?

Comment: Please provide the code, else setup demo at JSFIDDLE

Answer (score 1):

Use `scrollLeft` to reset the div scrollbar, before applying `overflow:hidden`.

**for eg :**

```
<div id="scrollContainer" style="width:300px; overflow:auto">
    <div class="lableContainer" style="width:500px">
    </div>
</div>
```

To `reset` the scrollbar before applying `overflow:hidden`:

```
$("#scrollContainer").scrollLeft(0);
$("#scrollContainer").css("overflow","hidden");
```

Comment: Was kinda slow, but may be will be helpful anyway. [Demo at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnmu7y7y/)